# Coverting Date Format in Hive

Tags: datetime, hadoop, twitter, hive

I have downloaded twitter data in hdfs and have successfully created hive table on it. Twitter gives the date format 'Thu Dec 10 06:21:00 +0000 2015' in the json file and i want to convert this format into 'yyy-MM-dd' i have tried built in functions provided by hive but they are not accepting the format provided by twitter. Can anyone help me convert this format.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an UDF is overkill and all you want is a quick fix, e.g. some RegExp massaging of that ugly format *(caveat: it's your job to test it thoroughly against all kinds of Twitter dates, and adapt the massaging accordingly)*

```
select TWITTER_VOMIT
 , regexp_extract(TWITTER_VOMIT, '^[A-Z][a-z]* ([A-Z][a-z]*) ([0-9][0-9]*) .* ([0-9]*)$', 3) as YYYY
 , regexp_extract(TWITTER_VOMIT, '^[A-Z][a-z]* ([A-Z][a-z]*) ([0-9][0-9]*) .* ([0-9]*)$', 1) as MON
 , regexp_extract(TWITTER_VOMIT, '^[A-Z][a-z]* ([A-Z][a-z]*) ([0-9][0-9]*) .* ([0-9]*)$', 2) as DD
 , concat(regexp_extract(TWITTER_VOMIT, '^[A-Z][a-z]* ([A-Z][a-z]*) ([0-9][0-9]*) .* ([0-9]*)$', 3)
         ,case regexp_extract(TWITTER_VOMIT, '^[A-Z][a-z]* ([A-Z][a-z]*) ([0-9][0-9]*) .* ([0-9]*)$', 1)
            when 'Jan' then '-01-'
            when 'Feb' then '-02-'
            when 'Mar' then '-03-'
            when 'Apr' then '-04-'
            when 'May' then '-05-'
            when 'Jun' then '-06-'
            when 'Jul' then '-07-'
            when 'Aug' then '-08-'
            when 'Sep' then '-09-'
            when 'Oct' then '-10-'
            when 'Nov' then '-11-'
            when 'Dec' then '-12-'
            else '-**-'
          end
         ,regexp_extract(TWITTER_VOMIT, '^[A-Z][a-z]* ([A-Z][a-z]*) ([0-9][0-9]*) .* ([0-9]*)$', 2)
         ) as YYYY_MM_DD
from TWITTER_FEED
```

For your example

```
twitter_vomit                   yyyy  mon  dd  yyyy_mm_dd
Thu Dec 10 06:21:00 +0000 2015  2015  Dec  10  2015-12-10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop java based UDF similar to this:
Once it is developed, you need to compile to jar ship it to cluster, add the jar file and create temporary function.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class DateTranslate extends UDF {
    public String evaluate(Text str) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("<SOURCE_DATE_FORMAT>");
        String transactionDate = null;
        try {
            transactionDate = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") //2013-01-03
                    .format(formatter.parse(str.toString())))
                    .toString();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return transactionDate;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UDF:

```
package org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.dateparser;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class dateparserHive extends UDF {
    public String evaluate(Text str) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy");
        String twitterDate = null;
        try {
            twitterDate = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    .format(formatter.parse(str.toString())))
                    .toString();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return twitterDate;

    }

}
```

Step 1: Create a jar file out of this. Copy this jar file in local file system

Step 2: Open Hive Terminal:

Step 3: ADD JAR /home/oxigen/dateparser.jar;

Step 4: create temporary function dateparsertwitter as 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.dateparser.dateparserHive';

Step 5: select dateparsertwitter('Wed Mar 02 09:56:41 +0000 2016') from twitter limit 1;

This should work fine!